# Nested dynamic structure in C?

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, struct

Is it possible to have two flexible-sized array within one structure ?

I know I can do something like below

```
struct A {
    int countB;
    struct B[0];
}
```

But my question is can we do something like below ?

```
struct A {
    int countB;
    struct B[0];
    int countC;
    struct C[0];
}
```

If yes, how would we get the offset of countC ?

If the above is very hard to implement, is there any other easy to tackle these kind of situations?

Comment: You would normally use dynamic allocation here, unless there's some reason not to.

Comment: It's not possible, the offset of `countC` could not be known at compile time. Zero-sized arrays are a GCC extension anyway, and in C99 have been superseded by actual flexible-sized arrays with a slightly different syntax.

Comment: The simplest solution is to use array pointers for the arrays, allocated independently from the `struct`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you are not allowed more than one flexible-size array per data structure:

> 6.7.2.1.16: As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one named member may have an incomplete array type; this is called a flexible array member.

The reason why the flexible array member must be the last one is that otherwise it would be impossible to compute the offset (the number of bytes relative to the address of the initial member of the `struct`) for any member following the flexible array member.

In your case a work-around is possible, at the expense of storing an extra pointer *before* the flexible member, pointing to the location of `C` inside `B`:

```
struct A {
    int countB;
    int countC;
    struct some_struct *C;
    struct some_struct B[0];
};
```

When you allocate `struct A`, you need to allocate an additional size of `countB+countC`. Member `C` needs to be set to the address of `B+countB`.